# Program won't display info in while loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to teach myself C++ and I was working on a login system as a way to help better my understanding. I am facing an issue however, the program will not print out anything inside the while loop I made, there are no syntax errors showing when I try to run it and the program doesn't end, it just sits there until I terminate it.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {

//existing users lists
    std::list<std::string> Username = {""};
    std::list<std::string> Password = {""};

//create account
    std::string newUsername;
    std::string newPassword;

//login info
    std::string existingUser;
    std::string existingPass;

//put new info in account lists
    Username.push_back(newUsername);
    Password.push_back(newPassword);

//creating account input
    std::cout << "Create a Username: ";
    std::cin >> newUsername;
    std::cout << "Create a Password: ";
    std::cin >> newPassword;

//login account input
    std::cout << "Enter your Username: ";
    std::cin >> existingUser;
    std::cout << "Enter your Password: ";
    std::cin >> existingPass;

//check if info is in database
   while (std::cin >> existingUser &&
   std::find(std::begin(Username), std::end(Username), existingUser) == std::end(Username)) {

//if password is in list continue
       if (std::cin >> existingPass &&
           std::find(std::begin(Password), std::end(Password), existingPass) == std::end(Password)) {

//Welcome message
           std::cout << "Welcome " << existingUser << ", Thank you for logging in !!\n";
           break;

       }

//if password isn't in list
       else (std::cin >> existingPass &&
       std::find(std::begin(Password), std::end(Password), existingPass) != std::end(Password)); {

// Try again message
           std::cout << "Incorrect username or password, Try Again.\n";
           std::cout << "Username: ";
           std::cin >> existingUser;
           std::cout << "Password: ";
           std::cin >> existingPass;

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the order you have for inputting the username and password and when you add them to the lists. Seems you'd want to input before adding them. You also might think about the logic a bit. You input the existing username and password then the while loop is going to wait for you to type the username again. The logic for `find` also seems reversed. `it == end` means it was not found, and `it != end` means it was and the iterator points to the found item.

Comment: My advice: stop whatever you are doing and learn to debug!! Debugging is an indispensable tool for a programmer. Without it you just stare at the code for hours wondering what is wrong. When instead you can step through your code line by line inspecting it and seeing exactly what is happening and where the expected behavior diverges from the actual behavior. Seriously, learn to debug! I can't stress enough how important it is!

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you I did seem to have the logic reversed. How would I get the "try again" to loop back to the while statement? Also thank you for explaining!!

Comment: @bolov thank you for the advice, I will keep that in mind! I could definitely work on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {

//existing users lists
std::list<std::string> Username = {""};
std::list<std::string> Password = {""};

//create account
std::string newUsername;
std::string newPassword;

//login info
std::string existingUser;
std::string existingPass;


//creating account input
std::cout << "Create a Username: ";
std::cin >> newUsername;
std::cout << "Create a Password: ";
std::cin >> newPassword;

//put new info in account lists
Username.push_back(newUsername);
Password.push_back(newPassword);

//login account input
std::cout << "Enter your Username: ";
std::cin >> existingUser;
std::cout << "Enter your Password: ";
std::cin >> existingPass;

 //check if info is in database
 while (std::cin >> existingUser &&
     std::find(std::begin(Username), std::end(Username), existingUser) == std::end(Username)) {

   //if password is in list continue
   if (std::cin >> existingPass &&
       std::find(std::begin(Password), std::end(Password), existingPass) == std::end(Password)) {

   //Welcome message
       std::cout << "Welcome " << existingUser << ", Thank you for logging in !!\n";
       break;

   }

   //if password isn't in list
   else (std::cin >> existingPass &&
   std::find(std::begin(Password), std::end(Password), existingPass) != std::end(Password)); {

   // Try again message
       std::cout << "Incorrect username or password, Try Again.\n";
       std::cout << "Username: ";
       std::cin >> existingUser;
       std::cout << "Password: ";
       std::cin >> existingPass;

     }
   }
 }
```

You are assigning value to the newUsername after pushing them to the list. Try to swap the code as shown above

Comment: This fixes one problem but there are many more.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out!! Was able to get it running perfectly!